# Stylus: Iterate multiple selectors for one rule

Tags: css, preprocessor, stylus

I want to iterate a selector with a different number to create multiple selectors separated with commas assigned to one rule.

I made a search but didn't found any similar example on the documentation.

**I was trying on with the following code:**

```
for num in (1..6)
  .foo-{num}
    color #dfd
```

But get multiple rules too.

**What I would like to achive is the following:**

```
.foo-1,
.foo-2,
.foo-3,
.foo-4,
.foo-5,
.foo-6 {
  color: #dfd;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join(range)
  str = ''
  for n in range
    str += ',.foo-' + n

{join(1..5)}
  color: #dfd
```

http://stylus-lang.com/docs/iteration.html#functions

EDIT: solution for problem mentioned in comment

```
multisize(sizes, before, after)
  str = ''
  for size in sizes
    str += before + size + after + ','

{multisize(xs sm lg, 'cs.btn-', '.btn-blue:hover')}
  color: #dfd
```

Comment: Hello how can I make to erease the seudo selector if used, for example if I use `&:hover` I get and empty `:hover,` at the beginning.`:hover,
.cs-btn-xs.btn-blue:hover,
.cs-btn-sm.btn-blue:hover`

Comment: Your solution was great! but I didn't realize how to solve the empty pseudo elements when used on my rules.

Comment: Sorry, must've missed your first comment. I updated my answer with solution to problem you mentioned in comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@extend` you get the selectors separated by comma, you can use a placeholder selector for the rules:

**Stylus**

```
$rules
  color #dfd

for num in (1..6)
  .foo-{num}
    @extend $rules
```

**Output**

```
.foo-1,
.foo-2,
.foo-3,
.foo-4,
.foo-5,
.foo-6 {
  color: #dfd;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was the indent, now it works, why stylus is so picky with the format of indention

Comment: Is it possible to use extend and then set the rules just before the `for num in (1..6)
  .foo-{num}` and remove this: `$rules
  color #dfd`

Comment: But you need a rule to extend

Answer (score 0):

It can also be achieved using [`+cache(key)`](https://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#cachekeys), where `key` is a unique string

```
for num in (1..6)
  .foo-{num}
    +cache('foo')
      color #f00
```

```
.foo-1,
.foo-2,
.foo-3,
.foo-4,
.foo-5,
.foo-6 {
  color: #f00;
}
```